# Atom does not recognise linting errors with create-react-app

Tags: eslint, create-react-app, atom-editor

When I create a new React app via the `npx create-react-app my-app` command, linting errors do not get flagged within the editor. They still appear in the terminal when the app is run of course.

- create-react-app: v.5.0.0
- react: v.17.0.2
- npm: v.8.1.2
- editor: Atom v.1.60.0

Atom Linting Packages:

- jsonlint v.1.1.4
- linter v3.4.0
- linter-eslint 9.0.0
- linter-ui-default 3.4.1

Any ideas of why this might be?

*Note:* I've got other projects linting properly with Atom, just not sure why base CRA does not lint.